# What do add to prop/raise the curtain rod a few inches away from the wall?

Tags: bedroom, curtain-rail

I am about to install a curtain rod onto the wall. The problem is I want to add a few inches between the curtain and the wall than the default length by the curtain rod.

I wonder if there is any item and what it is called (so I can find it in hardware stores). The item will be between the curtain rod and the wall to add a few inches of distance, plus it should be sturdy but allow a screw to go through. Ideally the shape should be close to the base of the curtain rod to make it looks like the extension, but if is not, it's also fine. Is this called some kind of spacer?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what is the item in the pictures? ... how does it relate to your question about spacers?

Comment: This is an end piece of the curtain rod

Comment: is it a part of the curtain rod, or is it a bracket that holds the curtain rod? ... i am assuming that the two holes are for attaching the item to the wall ... it is unclear what the threaded end is used for

Comment: a round wooden disk between 2" and 4" in diameter may look acceptable .... cut out the shape out of heavy cardboard to see what it would look like .... stack multiple cardboard pieces to get a better idea of the finished product

Answer (score 2):

Make a couple of nicely finished wooden blocks.

Can be painted same as the wall or to match / contrast with the support you show.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the Nevada desert, old west. I would simply get an old 2x4 or similar, sand it lightly, fix the surface with spray lacquer or polyurethane, and attach that between the anchor and the wall. If you are near the beach, a piece of driftwood may work. If you are an urbanite, use of a piece of pallet may work. Something that fits with the decor you have in your home. Another example, builders often stash extra pieces of tile or wood trim that are not needed, somewhere in the home. That may give you the space you need and seem like it is art, not a patch.